"error: Error: 1:183:invalid expression" React Native Metro Bundle Hermes Error
Got the following metro bundling error (both for iOS and Android) after starting migration from React Native 0.66.0 to React Native 0.71.4 using this tool https://react-native-community.github.io/upgrade-helper/?from=0.66.0&to=0.71.4

error: Error: 1:183:invalid expression
    at module.exports.compile (/Users/nezort11/dev/walnuts/node_modules/metro-hermes-compiler/src/index.js:107:15)
    at _getPrelude (/Users/nezort11/dev/walnuts/node_modules/metro/src/lib/getPrependedScripts.js:99:21)
    at getPrependedScripts (/Users/nezort11/dev/walnuts/node_modules/metro/src/lib/getPrependedScripts.js:66:5)
    at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)
    at async IncrementalBundler.buildGraph (/Users/nezort11/dev/walnuts/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js:147:21)
    at async /Users/nezort11/dev/walnuts/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js:181:34
    at async IncrementalBundler.initializeGraph (/Users/nezort11/dev/walnuts/node_modules/metro/src/IncrementalBundler.js:198:24)
    at async build (/Users/nezort11/dev/walnuts/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:678:35)
    at async Server.requestProcessor [as _processBundleRequest] (/Users/nezort11/dev/walnuts/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:587:18)
    at async Server._processRequest (/Users/nezort11/dev/walnuts/node_modules/metro/src/Server.js:397:9)

Packages:
"dependencies": {
    "@apeswapfinance/sdk": "git+https://github.com/fusmanii/apeswap-sdk.git\\#canary",
    "@dillionverma/react-native-swipe-button": "^1.1.3",
    "@ethersproject/shims": "^5.7.0",
    "@gorhom/bottom-sheet": "^4",
    "@json-rpc-tools/utils": "^1.7.6",
    "@metamask/eth-sig-util": "^4.0.1",
    "@rainbow-me/animated-charts": "https://github.com/bhowmikp/react-native-animated-charts",
    "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage": "^1.15.16",
    "@react-native-community/clipboard": "^1.5.1",
    "@react-native-community/netinfo": "^11.3.2",
    "@react-native-firebase/app": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/auth": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-native-firebase/messaging": "^14.11.0",
    "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view": "^0.2.6",
    "@react-navigation/bottom-tabs": "^6.0.9",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
    "@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^6.1.1",
    "@squirrelswap/sdk": "^1.0.1",
    "@tradle/react-native-http": "^2.0.0",
    "@types/react-csv": "^1.1.3",
    "@walletconnect/react-native-compat": "^2.13.1",
    "@walletconnect/web3wallet": "^1.12.0",
    "assert": "^1.1.1",
    "asyncstorage-down": "^4.2.0",
    "axios": "^0.24.0",
    "bignumber.js": "^9.0.2",
    "bip39": "^3.0.4",
    "browserify-zlib": "~0.1.4",
    "buffer": "^4.9.1",
    "console-browserify": "^1.1.0",
    "constants-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "decimal.js": "^10.3.1",
    "dns.js": "^1.0.1",
    "domain-browser": "^1.1.1",
    "ethereumjs-wallet": "^1.0.2",
    "ethers": "^5.7.2",
    "events": "^3.3.0",
    "fast-text-encoding": "^1.0.6",
    "formik": "^2.2.9",
    "https-browserify": "~0.0.0",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "jetifier": "^2.0.0",
    "jwt-decode": "^3.1.2",
    "levelup": "^5.1.1",
    "libphonenumber-js": "^1.9.43",
    "link-check": "https://github.com/boillodmanuel/link-check",
    "paraswap-core": "^1.0.2",
    "patch-package": "^6.4.7",
    "path-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "postinstall-postinstall": "^2.1.0",
    "punycode": "^1.2.4",
    "querystring-es3": "~0.2.0",
    "react": "18.2.0",
    "react-native": "0.71.4",
    "react-native-animated-styles": "^0.9.0",
    "react-native-autolink": "^4.0.0",
    "react-native-avoid-softinput": "^2.4.8",
    "react-native-base64": "^0.2.1",
    "react-native-camera": "^4.2.1",
    "react-native-console-time-polyfill": "^1.2.3",
    "react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.1",
    "react-native-create-thumbnail": "^2.0.0",
    "react-native-crypto": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-device-info": "^8.7.0",
    "react-native-directory-picker": "^0.0.2",
    "react-native-document-picker": "^7.1.0",
    "react-native-dotenv": "^3.3.0",
    "react-native-elements": "4.0.0-rc.2",
    "react-native-encrypted-storage": "^4.0.2",
    "react-native-fast-image": "^8.6.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
    "react-native-get-random-values": "^1.7.2",
    "react-native-haptic-feedback": "^1.13.0",
    "react-native-image-colors": "^1.5.0",
    "react-native-keyboard-aware-scroll-view": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-keychain": "^8.0.0",
    "react-native-level-fs": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^2.5.6",
    "react-native-os": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-pager-view": "^5.4.17",
    "react-native-permissions": "^3.3.1",
    "react-native-progress": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-qrcode-scanner": "^1.5.5",
    "react-native-qrcode-svg": "^6.1.2",
    "react-native-randombytes": "^3.0.0",
    "react-native-raw-bottom-sheet": "^2.2.0",
    "react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.3",
    "react-native-redash": "^16.2.3",
    "react-native-safe-area-context": "^3.3.2",
    "react-native-screens": "^3.7.2",
    "react-native-skeleton-placeholder": "^5.0.0",
    "react-native-svg": "^12.3.0",
    "react-native-svg-flagkit": "^0.9.5",
    "react-native-swipeout": "^2.3.6",
    "react-native-tab-view": "^3.1.1",
    "react-native-tcp": "^3.2.1",
    "react-native-udp": "^2.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^9.0.0",
    "react-native-video": "https://github.com/MatrixFrog/react-native-video#11ca8a6799f932a5f24da85dfe68c696ad13a753",
    "react-native-webview": "^13.8.6",
    "readable-stream": "1.0.33",
    "rn-biometric-authentication": "^1.0.2",
    "rn-fetch-blob": "^0.12.0",
    "rn-nodeify": "^10.3.0",
    "rn-swipe-button": "^1.3.6",
    "shamirs-secret-sharing-ts": "^1.0.2",
    "stream": "^0.0.2",
    "stream-browserify": "^1.0.0",
    "string_decoder": "~0.10.25",
    "tailwind-rn": "^3.0.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^2.2.15",
    "timers-browserify": "^1.0.1",
    "tty-browserify": "0.0.0",
    "url": "~0.10.1",
    "util": "~0.10.3",
    "uuid": "^8.3.2",
    "vm-browserify": "0.0.4",
    "wallet-address-validator": "^0.2.4",
    "webview": "^1.0.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/core": "^7.21.0",
    "@babel/helper-get-function-arity": "^7.16.7",
    "@babel/plugin-proposal-decorators": "^7.18.6",
    "@babel/preset-env": "^7.20.0",
    "@babel/preset-typescript": "^7.17.12",
    "@babel/runtime": "^7.21.0",
    "@types/jest": "^29.2.1",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.24",
    "@types/react-native": "^0.71.4",
    "@types/react-native-base64": "^0.2.0",
    "@types/react-native-countdown-component": "^2.7.0",
    "@types/react-native-video": "^5.0.13",
    "@types/react-test-renderer": "^18.0.0",
    "@types/uuid": "^8.3.4",
    "@typescript-eslint/eslint-plugin": "4.31.2",
    "@typescript-eslint/parser": "4.31.2",
    "@walletconnect/jsonrpc-types": "^1.0.4",
    "babel-jest": "^26.6.3",
    "eslint": "^7.14.0",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-prettier": "3.4.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.26.0",
    "eslint-plugin-react-native": "^3.11.0",
    "eslint-plugin-simple-import-sort": "^7.0.0",
    "jest": "^26.6.3",
    "metro-react-native-babel-preset": "0.73.8",
    "prettier": "^2.4.1",
    "react-native-codegen": "^0.0.7",
    "react-test-renderer": "17.0.2",
    "typescript": "^4.8.4"
  },
  "resolutions": {
    "@types/react": "^17",
    "@rainbow-me/animated-charts/**/react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
    "@rainbow-me/animated-charts/**/react-native-reanimated": "^2.14.3",
    "react-native-gesture-handler": "2.9.0",
    "clipboardy": "3.0.0",
    "@react-native-community/cli-plugin-metro": "^10.2.0"
  },

yarn.lock

metro version is 0.73.10
metro-hermes-compiler version is 0.73.10

Errors comes from here:
https://github.com/facebook/metro/blob/0.73/0.73.10/packages/metro-hermes-compiler/src/index.js#L131
I still don't know how is metro-hermes-compiler (which was removed in metro@0.76.9) related to metro when i have hermes disabled:
gradle.properties
# Use this property to enable or disable the Hermes JS engine.
# If set to false, you will be using JSC instead.
hermesEnabled=false

and
Podfile
  use_react_native!(
    # # to enable hermes on iOS, change `false` to `true` and then install pods
    :hermes_enabled => false,
  )

